# Download file in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, files

I'm receiving a link to a file once the component is loaded, and i want to download it.

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Download" title="Download" icon-position="right" icon-name="utility:download" onclick = {downloadClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

When i press the `Download` button, i want to download the file in thr url i received.

I tried creating an `a` tag in js, and clicking it. it redirects me to the link instead of downloading it:

```
downloadClick() {
    let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
    downloadElement.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg';
    downloadElement.target = '_self';
    downloadElement.download = 'download.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
    downloadElement.click(); 
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1. In html file paste this:

> < div lwc:dom="manual" class="download-container" >< /div >

2. Use this method to download your file:

> ```
> handleDownloadPdf() {
> const downloadContainer = this.template.querySelector('.download-container');
> const downloadUrl = [link to file];
> const fileName = [title of file];
>
> let a = document.createElement('a');
> a.href = downloadUrl;
> a.target = '_parent';
> // Use a.download if available, it prevents plugins from opening.
> a.download = fileName;
> // Add a to the doc for click to work.
> if (downloadContainer) {
>   downloadContainer.appendChild(a);
> }
> if (a.click) {
>   a.click(); // The click method is supported by most browsers.
> }
> // Delete the temporary link.
> downloadContainer.removeChild(a);
> // Download the next file with a small timeout. The timeout is necessary
> // for IE, which will otherwise only download the first file.   }
> ```

3. I recomend you to use fileAssets (Files) , later on you can use relative link , for example "**/file-asset/abcPdfToDownload**".

Answer (score 0):

**As of Chrome 65 this is no longer possible for cross-origin hrefs.**

<s>You're actually incredibly close. I made it work using the snippet below. Setting the boolean 'download' attribute for the anchor tag seems important for jpgs, and I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work if you append/ set target to self.</s>

```
let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
downloadElement.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg';
downloadElement.setAttribute("download","download");
downloadElement.download = 'download.jpg';
downloadElement.click();
```

Comment: What if it's not a jpeg? do i need to use "target = '_self'" ?

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Strange - it executes without issue in Chrome dev tools. I do something similar for PDFs and there only define href and download:

let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                    downloadLink.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+result.pdfContentData;
                    downloadLink.download = "file.pdf";
                    downloadLink.click();

Comment: Stranger still, I just tried it again myself and it only re-directed not downloaded. I'll update my answer shortly once resolved.

Comment: Please do, i am lost :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey @DanaGriff - I believe this might be impossible since Chrome 65 :( https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download

Is your image hosted as a static resource/ Salesforce file?

Comment: i'm not using an image. i used one for this example but it will be a zip file. I will call an external service that will generate a link. The link expires in 10 minutes. I get the link and i need to download the file.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Ahh, that might change things. I've looked at how we're doing this for some PDFs in our org and it turns out we make a callout (via an Apex controller) to retrieve the pdf's data first, then generate the download link. Would this be an option for you?

Comment: i will be receiving a zip file, will that work? if so, please post your answer.

Comment: I recommend reading through the various answers in this thread and seeing if any of them works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713

Answer (score 0):

The answers listed above did not work for me. I would highly recommend downloading the "FileSaver" JS library (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

After you download them, you'll add them as static resources, then include them in your component.

In LWC, the code will something like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import FileSaver from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/FileSaver';

export default class DownloadExample extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.loadScripts();
    }

    // Load JavaScript libraries
    async loadScripts() {
        // Load FileSaver
        await loadScript(this, FileSaver)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('FileSaver loaded');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error loading FileSaver');
        });
    }

    // Save a file with a custom filename
    async downloadAs(url, filename) {
        let resp = await fetch(url);
        let fileBlob = await resp.blob();

        saveAs(fileBlob, filename);
    }

    // Example download
    saveFile() {
        let url = 'https://someurl.com/download';
        let filename = 'This is my custom filename.txt';

        this.downloadAs(url, filename);
    }
}
```

This method has worked great for me. I also use the JsZip library (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) for downloading multiple files or folders as a Zip file. Just remember that if you want the downloader to reside in a child component that the libraries should load in the parent component (so they exist when the parent loads).

Answer (score -3):

```
 <a href={source} download></a>
```

You can use this in html, define the source in js and on click the 'download' tag will download the file. This only works for 'a' tag.

Comment: This is very similar to Dan Wareing's answer from 3 years ago.