Downloading a CSV file in LWC
I am trying to implement a feature to download a CSV file in a Salesforce Experience Cloud site. I have tried two different approaches, but neither has worked as expected.
Approach 1: Using Custom Metadata
I created a custom metadata type that stores the URL to the CSV file. I then created an Apex class to retrieve the URL for use in LWC. Here's the code:
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Template_URL__mdt> getTemplateURLs() {
    return [SELECT Label, URL__c FROM Template_URL__mdt];
}

handleDownloadTemplate(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
    const templateURL = this.templateURLs[selectedValue];
    if (templateURL) {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute("href", this.staticResourceURL);
        link.setAttribute("download", this.selectedTemplate + '.csv');
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
        this.handleError('Template not found', 'error');
    }
}

This approach did not work; while the URL retrieves correctly and I can download the file manually by opening the URL in the browser, nothing downloads when I trigger the link programmatically.
Approach 2: Using Static Resource
As a second approach, I uploaded the CSV file as a static resource and tried using that as the download URL. Unfortunately, I encountered the same issue where the file does not download through the LWC.
Question:
What is the best approach or best practice for downloading files (specifically CSV files) in a Salesforce Experience Cloud site using LWC and Apex? Are there any specific configurations or methods I should be aware of?
Thank you for your assistance!

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  What specific action calls handleDownloadTemplate?  Are you trying to force the download to occur without any user interaction on the page?

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292006/download-file-in-lwc, one of the first few hits when searching for a way to download a file using lwc, maybe try this out?

have you tried this approach: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_file_download.htm&release=240&type=5?
import { generateUrl } from 'lightning/fileDownload';
const url = generateUrl(recordId);
window.open(url);
How: Import the generateURL method from lightning/fileDownload. Pass the recordId of the file to the generateURL method to create a URL to download the file. Use window.open(url) to download the file with the generated URL.
ContentDocument and ContentVersion files download automatically.
Attachments and Documents open in a new browser tab for preview and download.
